Change upper case strings to proper case
I'm trying to figure out how to run a VBA script in which I run a formula to correct for upper case strings.
I want to change values if the cell is True on
Exact(X,Upper(X))

Something like
If Exact(A1,Upper(A1)) = true then
    x.Value = Application.Proper(x.Value)
ENDIF

and repeat.
I am checking specific ranges.
Dim LastRow As Long
Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit

LastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(ActiveSheet.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

' Loop to cycle through each cell in the specified range.
For Each x In Range("B1:M" & LastRow)
    x.Value = Application.Proper(x.Value)
Next

Range("A1").Select

End Sub


You can use the Ucase method
 For Each x In Range("B1:M" & LastRow)
    If x.Value = Ucase(x.Value) then            
        x.Value = Application.Proper(x.Value)
    End If
   Next


Make Proper If Upper
Option Explicit

Sub UpperToProper()
   
    ' Reference the worksheet.
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet
    
    ' Reference the range.
    Dim rg As Range:
    Set rg = ws.Range("B1:M" & ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row)
    
    ' Return the values of the range in an array.
    Dim Data() As Variant: Data = rg.Value
    
    ' Modify the strings in the array.
    
    Dim cCount As Long: cCount = rg.Columns.Count
    
    Dim Value As Variant, r As Long, c As Long
    
    For r = 1 To rg.Rows.Count
        For c = 1 To cCount
            Value = Data(r, c)
            If VarType(Value) = vbString Then ' is of type String
                If Value = UCase(Value) Then ' is upper case
                    Data(r, c) = Application.Proper(Value) ' make proper case
                End If
            End If
        Next c
    Next r
    
    ' Copy the values from the array to the range.
    rg.Value = Data
    rg.EntireColumn.AutoFit ' or 'ws.UsedRange.EntireColumn.AutoFit'
    
    ' Inform.
    MsgBox "Upper-cased converted to proper-cased.", vbInformation

End Sub

